# Trying to globally register components automatically in Vue using Laravel-Mix and Webpack-Mix

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, laravel-mix

Previously when working on projects using Vue (based in a Laravel-Mix/Webpack runtime environment) I would register components and views individually as needed using imports and Vue.extend:

```
import BaseButton from './components/BaseButton.vue'
import BaseIcon from './components/BaseIcon.vue'
import BaseInput from './components/BaseInput.vue'

window.base = Vue.extend {
  components: {
    BaseButton,
    BaseIcon,
    BaseInput
  }
}
```

Which I could then convert into a rendered JS file using webpack.mix.js:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.vue({
        version: 2
    })
        .js('src/js/base.js', 'dist/base_rendered.js')
```

then reference the converted file in a `<script>` within a given HTML file as needed:

```
<script src="base_rendered.js"></script>
<script>
   new base({
       el: '#base',

    });
</script>
```

This worked fine when I was working on a page or a few components at a time, but recently a NuxtJS-based project I was working on was required to be moved over to this Laravel-Mix/Webpack-type environment, and I have over 100 components which need to be registered, and all of which are likely to see use in the project's web pages.
(I build the components and they get sent out-of-house to be implemented)

So, I was looking into Vue's [documentation on automatic global registration of base components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Automatic-Global-Registration-of-Base-Components) for guidance. I've pasted their example code below:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import upperFirst from 'lodash/upperFirst'
import camelCase from 'lodash/camelCase'

const requireComponent = require.context(
  // The relative path of the components folder
  './components',
  // Whether or not to look in subfolders
  false,
  // The regular expression used to match base component filenames
  /Base[A-Z]\w+\.(vue|js)$/
)

requireComponent.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  // Get component config
  const componentConfig = requireComponent(fileName)

  // Get PascalCase name of component
  const componentName = upperFirst(
    camelCase(
      // Gets the file name regardless of folder depth
      fileName
        .split('/')
        .pop()
        .replace(/\.\w+$/, '')
    )
  )


  // Register component globally
  Vue.component(
    componentName,
    // Look for the component options on `.default`, which will
    // exist if the component was exported with `export default`,
    // otherwise fall back to module's root.
    componentConfig.default || componentConfig
  )
})
```

I can understand how the code could look into each file in the components folder and draw up a list of PascalCase component names, but the part I'm struggling with is how to then export the resultant list (using Vue.extend or other means), have it get rendered correctly with webpack.mix.js, then be able to cite it inside my HTML file's scripts so the components can be directly used inside my HTML file.

Thank you for any help you are able to give. The idea of trying to write up imports/exports for over 100 components is making me feel a bit ill.

(Also, my current setup using the individual method means that when I call on components in my HTML file, they're referenced with kebab case. Would this still be the case or do I need to reference them differently? I also have my own require.context set to true because I have sub-folders for each "chapter" of components in my library.)

Answer (score 0):

D'oh! As usual I was overthinking it. To complete the logic for this and export your list of components, all you have to do is create a new Vue after defining said list and specify the element it should point towards:

```
import upperFirst from 'lodash/upperFirst'
import camelCase from 'lodash/camelCase'

const requireComponent = require.context(
    './components/',
    true,
    /[A-Z]\w+\.(vue|js)$/
)

requireComponent.keys().forEach(fileName => {
    const componentConfig = requireComponent(fileName)

    const componentName = upperFirst(
        camelCase(
            fileName
            .split('/')
            .pop()
            .replace(/\.\w+$/, '')
        )
    )

    Vue.component(
        componentName,componentConfig.default || componentConfig
    )
})

window.components = Vue.extend({})
```

Now all of my components are registered in that extended Vue and I can use the same calling technique in the HTML files that I was using before!